# How can I find real estate auctions?

Tags: real-estate, massachusetts, auction

How can I find real estate auctions in my state (Massachusetts)?

I am mostly interested in land, vacant lots or commercial property, not residential properties with houses.

In the old days it was easy: all auctions were listed in a special section of the Boston Globe, but I have not been able to find any comparable listing on the web. I assume there is some legal requirement to post notices of auctions. How can I find them?

Comment: Might want to try and pick up a newspaper in your area, they probably still have that section.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the county tax assessor's office if you're looking for tax foreclosures and auctions of that nature.  You need to have cash in hand or proof of funds in order to participate, and you usually get very little time (or none at all sometimes) to look at the properties before bidding.  It's a very competitive market, but if you work at it hard enough you can score good deals.

Another thought would be to call some local realtors and ask them about auctions in the area.  They can definitely point you in the right direction.

I hope this helps

Good luck!